# Getting data with Httpclient and displaying it with JSON

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

I have to write a code that retrieves specific information (not all of it) from url.com/info/{CODE} and uses json to display it in a server I have up.
This is my code up until now:

A class to get the info

```
@RequestMapping("/info")
public class Controller {

    public void httpGET() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        String url = "Getfromhere.com/";

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    }
```

and a class that should return the data depending on the code inserted in the url by the user

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{iataCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public CloseableHttpResponse generate(@PathVariable String iataCode) {
    ;
    return response;

}
```

How I can implement json for the return?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you must configure Spring to use Jackson or some other API to convert all your responses to json.

If the data you are retrieving is already in json format, you can return it as String.

Your big mistake: right now you are returning an object of type `CloseableHttpResponse`. Change return type of `generate()` from `CloseableHttpResponse` to `String` and return a string.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String res = null;

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {

  InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(instream);

  res = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

  instream.close();

}

return res;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i'll try correcting the code and i'll get back if i have any more problems

Comment: It worked, I managed to get the program running the way I needed.